# How to use Regular Expression (Regex) in case of finding pattern in Dynamic Attributes of jsonb objects fetched from postgres query?

Tags: postgresql, jsonb

E.g. `{"AbcK12GM":"value1"}, {"CdRK12mf":"value2"}.`

Even though my example does not make any sense but in my project, i have a requirement to find a pattern in dynamic attribute.

Comment: What is the expected output based on that example? And why do you think you need  regex and not one of the many [JSON functions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-json.html)

Comment: For this specific example, i want output "value1", "value2" but in my acutal project scenario, i have nested object in which outer attribute is dynamic in nature. And i cannot use json functions as either attribute should be static or it should be outer one so that we can access its value by indexes.